# Custom Power BI Visuals

Tags: r, business-intelligence

Hi I am trying to Create a Custom Visual using NodeJS and PBIVIZ I have done installation etc. But I when I am adding values and trying to view the final plot I am getting the below error. Following is the code used

```
library(ggplot2)
dataset = values
g = ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=dataset$Buying,     
           fill=dataset$Car_Acceptibility)) + 
           geom_bar(stat="count") + 
           scale_x_discrete(name ="Buying Price") +
           scale_fill_discrete(name="Acceptability")

####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
Cannot Open File
```

[image: Custom Visual Error]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, BinitDubey! This could be for several reasons with a lot of speculation, I don't think anybody is going to be able to help much without more context at a minimum, more preferably a reproducible question. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269.

Comment: I read a blog on Custom Visuals in R and following is the Code that I am using in My script.r file in my --Rhtml folder
dataset = values
g = ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=dataset$Buying,     
           fill=dataset$Car_Acceptibility)) + 
           geom_bar(stat="count") + 
           scale_x_discrete(name ="Buying Price") +
           scale_fill_discrete(name="Acceptability")

####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');

Comment: Comments are not well-suited for large amounts of code/data, please [edit] your question and put it there. (Also, comments are often skipped by readers and/or hidden by the Stack interface, so it's best to keep the question complete.) Thanks!

Comment: But that code is about plotting it, nothing to do with reading in the data. Where in your script are you using `read.*`? How is your BI app setup for retrieving/accessing data? This is the context I was referring to earlier.

Comment: Doesn't Values that are used in Power Bi visual, flow into the R script. I am referring to (dataset = Values)

Comment: From the error, there's no indication it even gets to `dataset = values`. I have no idea how `values` is created, and your code makes no reference to `read.csv` or `file`, so it's difficult to know where to go with this.

Comment: @r2evans Power BI automatically runs `read.csv` and store in `values`.